# WordPress / Easy Facnybox Error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method “fancybox”

Tags: wordpress

I have installed the Easy Fancybox plugin but am getting some errors and cannot see why, so any help would be much appreciated.
Here is the link: `http://176.67.171.11/airvent/`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using the old fancybox which doesn't work with your jQuery library of `1.9.0` if you want to use the old fancybox, use version `1.8.3` of jQuery library otherwise update your fancybox which can be found [**here**](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/)

Comment: Thank you for solving that! I will contact the plugin author to update it for jQuery 1.9. if they will ;) In the meantime, I am now calling 1.8.3 and everything is working fine. Thanks again.

Comment: @HuwRowlands there is already a newer version of fancybox that works with 1.9 http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/